# Do I need to create same list for both get/post ActionResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need some directions on how to handle a list that I create and pass to my view with Viewbag. If there is something wrong with the model in POST I need to create and pass it again, otherwise I'll get an error for the Razor syntax.

Is there a better way to do this so that I don't have to create it again (querying my db)?
I guess Viewbag is out of the question, it was just a quick-fix.

```
    // GET
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        Person person = new Person();
        ViewBag.CountryList = Main.GetCountryList(); // for person.country string
        return View(Person);
    }

    // POST
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Person person)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ...
        }
        ViewBag.CountryList = Main.GetCountryList();
        return View(person);
    }
```

HTML/Razor:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.country, ViewBag.CountryList as SelectList)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you were to store that list in a session or something, then no, you would need to requery to get the list.

With that said, a few things to consider. A simple query for a drop down should not be that taxing on your server as well as, how often does one actually have a validation error (1 out of 10 times)?  With the combination of client side validation and not having an error every time, this should not make it to your post method all that often and forced to return back to the view.

Answer (score 1):

if `GetCountryList` is a static method you can use it directly in the Razor.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.country, Main.GetCountryList() as SelectList)
```

if you want to save querying DB repeatedly, you should implement caching for the CoutryList data using `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache` or as a static list if it is not going to change.